# Submission error with currency validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the field in my table with decimal and precision as follow:

```
change_column :product, :price, :decimal, precision: 20, scale: 10
```

and I set the validation like this

```
validates :price, numericality: true, format: { with: /^\d{1,20}(\.\d{0,10})?$/ }
```

When I have input value of **90,000.00** from client-side and try to save it; an error occurs as saying that it is not number.

Anyone has any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't add the comma in it..

Comment: how come if we it is default format we set up in rails? any more solution?

Comment: you can use some filter to clear the all commas or whatever you allowed extra characters in input. Like in your case you can use gsub(",","") to replace all commas by blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `before_validation` callback to format value of price to pe passed to validator.